# I'm facing these errors when I run command (npx react-native init AwesomeProject)

Tags: android, react-native

Downloading template
error Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@latest
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "react-native@latest"
npm ERR! node v14.15.1
npm ERR! npm v4.0.0

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-O81d4q\npm-debug.log

Comment: Are you running your cmd in administrator mode? have you upgraded your node.js version and have you tried with yarn?

Comment: I've tried it all but nothing worked.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and install again your latest node version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using npm 4, updating npm to a version >= 6 should fix your issue (which should come by default with Node 12 and 14) according to this issue [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34162#issuecomment-652575905).

You might also try [this solution](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874#issuecomment-663661148):

1. C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
2. Delete the npm folder and if there is one npm cache folder.
3. Run `npm cache clean —force` ( — force is now required to clean cache)